# Que Error Tiene esta Consulta? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal(
       IP varchar(15) NULL
    );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporal_2(
       IP varchar(15) NULL
    );

SELECT IF (NULL = (SELECT IP FROM temporal WHERE IP = '0' LIMIT 1),
    (INSERT INTO temporal_2(IP) VALUES ('1')),(SELECT NULL LIMIT 1));

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporal;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporal_2;
Error
```

**[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO temporal_2(IP) VALUES ('1')),(SELECT NULL LIMIT 1))' at line 2**

Quiero hacer esto de SQL server pero en MySQL. El equivalente a esto:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (IP varchar(15))

INSERT #Temp (IP)VALUES (0)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IP FROM #Temp WHERE IP = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Entro'
END

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que es lo que estas tratando de hacer a lo mejor y lo podemos hacer de otra forma

Comment: Estoy tratando o buscando que me funcione un If conoces algo de SQL server¿?

Comment: Creo que podrias evaluar primero el resultado de si cumple y eso lo guardad en una variable y tendrias que hacer luego un IF

Comment: Disculpe pero no le entiendo de hecho, si solicito respuesta es por que la desconozco creo no se.

Comment: En ambas podes trabajar con not exists...

Comment: Eso lo intente mire la imagen igual no funciona, Ojo uso navicat 11

Comment: Pero eso no quiere decir que tu error esté en el not exists, al fin y al cabo tienes un error lo uses o no(cual sería la diferencia?)... también aclarar que el hecho de que una consulta no devuelva nada no quiere decir que sea un null... No importa que lo hagas en navicat, la idea es que lo hagas en MySql

Comment: Además, en la imagen no usas tablas temporales, y al final del paréntesis tienes un punto y coma que no debería ir...  Por lo que puedo notar viendo tus ediciones, tu forma de realizar el código y tus errores, más que dudas en el ejercicio lo que te falta son fundamentos en SQL, te recomiendo que leas sobre sql antes de meterte a resolver ejercicios a ciegas. SO. te ayudará a encontrar una solución, pero la enseñanza parte de uno mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira si lo que quieres es saber por que no funciona tu IF, es simplemente por que lo debes de usar dentro de un procedimiento almacenado para hacer un insert:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temporal ()
 BEGIN
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temporal LIMIT 1)
THEN
INSERT INTO temporal_2  VALUES ('1');
ELSE
SELECT 'HAY DATO';
END IF;
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

de esta manera mandas a llamar el procedimiento :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como no hay datos en la tabla 'temporal' insertara en la 'tabla temporal_2'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora si insertas en la tabla 'temporal' te regresara esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ultimo si quieres utilizar condicionales es mejor usar CASE, sin embargo solo podrás hacer ciertas operaciones pero lo puedes usar fuera de un procedimiento:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temporal LIMIT 1) )
    THEN (SELECT 'NO HAY DATO')
    ELSE (SELECT 'HAY DATO')
END as prueba;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Exito hermano, gracias por su aporte solo un detalle pordria colocarlo en trigger. lo hice en modo trigger y si me funciono. por que al parecer la clasica de sql server nunca me pudo entrar